# Generic way to get SAS Table metadata URI

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

I'm building a utility that leverages the SAS metadata ID (or URI) of a table object.  The following code works fine for getting the ID when the library uses the BASE engine:

```
%let mylib=SOMELIB;
data output (keep=uri dataname);
  length uri $100 dataname $256;
  uri='';
  i=1;
  do until (rc<0);
    rc=metadata_getnasn("omsobj:SASLibrary?@Libref='&mylib'","Tables",i,uri);
    put rc=;
    prc=metadata_getattr(uri,"Name",dataname);
    if rc>=0 then output;
    i+1;
    put i=;
  end;
run;
```

However for other library engines (eg OLEDB, ODBC, REMOTE) SAS will store the information in different properties (eg under "UsingPackages/[my db]/Tables").  I can write conditional logic for each of the library engines I come across, but wondered if there was an easier / more generic way to get the Table ID?

The same issue occurs in reverse (if I search for the Table I still need the SASLibrary to ensure it is unique).

Answer (score 2):

The code in this article was extremely helpful for our SAS admins:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrmeta/63180/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1k9zipe59ha2an1pq34gu143lay.htm

> **Example: Listing Libraries and Their Server Contexts**
>
> This program uses the SAS metadata DATA step functions to return more
>   detailed information about the libraries. The results are returned to
>   a Libraries data set in the Work library. The requested data includes
>   the library metadata ID, the library name, libref, engine, path on the
>   file system (or if DBMS data, the DBMS path), and the server contexts
>   to which the library is associated.

It'll give you everything you want and more.

Comment: Thanks..  I'm resigned to the fact that a conditional script like the one you reference will be necessary.  Am nearly finished, and will post it here shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a macro for this today, located here: https://github.com/sasjs/core/blob/main/meta/mm_gettableid.sas

Reproduced below:

```
/**
  @file mm_gettableid.sas
  @brief Get the metadata id for a particular table
  @details Provide a libref and table name to return the corresponding metadata id
  in an output datataset.

  Usage:

      - get a table id
      %mm_gettableid(libref=METALIB,ds=SOMETABLE,outds=iwant)

  @param libref= The libref to search
  @param ds= The input dataset to check
  @param outds= the dataset to create that contains the `tableuri`
  @param mDebug= set to 1 to show debug messages in the log

  @returns outds  dataset containing `tableuri` and `tablename`

  @version 9.3
  @author Allan Bowe

**/

%macro mm_gettableid(
     libref=
    ,ds=
    ,outds=work.mm_gettableid
    ,mDebug=0
)/*/STORE SOURCE*/;

%local mD;
%if &mDebug=1 %then %let mD=;
%else %let mD=%str(*);
%&mD.put Executing &sysmacroname..sas;
%&mD.put _local_;

data &outds;
  length uri usingpkguri id type tableuri tablename tmpuri $256;
  call missing(of _all_);
  keep tableuri tablename;
  n=1;
  rc=0;
  if metadata_getnobj("omsobj:SASLibrary?@Libref='&libref'",n,uri)<1 then do;
    put "Library &libref not found";
    stop;
  end;
  &mD.putlog "uri is " uri;
  if metadata_getnasn(uri, "UsingPackages", 1, usingpkguri)>0 then do;
    rc=metadata_resolve(usingpkguri,type,id);
    &mD.putlog "Type is " type;
  end;

  if type='DatabaseSchema' then tmpuri=usingpkguri;
  else tmpuri=uri;
  
  t=1;
  do while(metadata_getnasn(tmpuri, "Tables", t, tableuri)>0);
    t+1;
    rc= metadata_getattr(tableuri, "Name", tablename);
    &mD.putlog "Table is " tablename;
    if upcase(tablename)="%upcase(&ds)" then do;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

%mend;
```