# Adjust Metadata URI to Exclude WorkTable Metadata Type

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

I've built the code below for getting a list of SAS registered tables from metadata.  It works fine but takes a long time to run due to the large volume of WorkTables (a [subtype](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/omamodref/61849/HTML/default/viewer.htm#physicaltable.htm) of PhysicalTable):

```
data work.tables (keep=uri name);
  length uri name $256;
  n=1;
  do while(metadata_getnobj("omsobj:PhysicalTable?@Id contains '.'",n,uri)>=0);
    n+1;
    if substr(uri,8,9)='WorkTable' then continue;
    if metadata_getattr(uri, "SASTableName", name)=0 then output;
  end;
run;
```

Is there any way to adjust the uri so that the WorkTable type can be excluded in the metadata query itself?

Eg as follows (doesn't work):

```
omsobj:PhysicalTable?@Id contains '.' and @MetadataType ne 'WorkTable'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the following URI did the trick, although it was only 20% faster:

```
omsobj:PhysicalTable?@Id contains '.' and @PublicType = 'Table'
```

This can of course be shortened to:

```
omsobj:PhysicalTable?@PublicType = 'Table'
```

Which shaved off an extra 0.2 seconds.